# Find private Key from a set of public keys

Tags: private-key, public-key, recovery

my old laptop suddenly died and I need to recover my private/pub keys.
I manage to recover the files from the HD but I have around 400 private keys.
I know tho, my public key.
Is it possible to figured out which one is the right private key associated to that specific public key, looking among a set of 400 keys?

Any tips is very welcome!

Comment: Yes, in general it is possible to match public keys to their private key mates if you have both.

Comment: Yes, i do have both. Is there any program that can help me find the right one?
Or how can I do it? I cannot manually try the 400 private keys...

Comment: It sounds off-topic, stackoverflow is for questions about programming. However, any answer would be contingent on what kinds of keys they are. There are all kinds of formats for public/private keys, designed for all sorts of different purposes.

Comment: it might be off topic.. not sure whereelse I would ask that. 
Are the keys used for ssh to a server. The one used with Github for example